# What's that vocal effect? Or is it natural?

Tags: effects, vocals

I'm an AVP n00b, so bare with me.
I've been wondering about a vocal sound that I'm very fond of. Some vocalists over the years have been using it, but it's not really that common. The sound is very soft, full-bodied and has a sort emphasis on making the consonant sounds really soft. My question is: Do they have these voices all natural, or is it some effect that they are using, that could be applied to any voice? (flang effect maybe?)

Here are two examples:

John Grant - Queen of Denmark
http://open.spotify.com/track/77jhNH7WU1qR60BlDOZpGh

Gerry Rafferty - Right Down The Line
http://open.spotify.com/track/2Xb6wJYGi0QXwURw5WWvI5

Comment: Do you have examples on another site like http://freemusicarchive.org or http://soundcloud.com?  Perhaps the preview on http://amazon.com/music ...

Comment: Here is an example of the John Grant song on [Amazon music](http://www.amazon.com/Queen-Denmark-John-Grant/dp/B00383XZQC/ref=sr_1_1?s=music&ie=UTF8&qid=1334174349&sr=1-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Gerry Rafferty one, it sounds like he might be using a mild chorus effect, but aside from that I can't hear anything else - it's just his voice.

A chorus can make a vocal sound fuller, as if you had your voice multi-tracked at slightly varying pitch.

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad to hear that Gerry's voice is (almost) natural :)

Answer (score 3):

The John Grant song samples [linked from the comment](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00383XZQC) are a mixture of chorus, short delays, and reverb.  I don't see the connection between the effects I mainly hear and your "soft consonants" observation.

My best guess is you should research [compression](https://video.stackexchange.com/search?q=compression) and/or [vocal doubling](https://www.google.com/search?q=vocal%20doubling) (and [pop filters](https://www.google.com/search?q=pop%20filter) if you need one) to achieve the sound you want.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have the rep yet to vote up your answer, but I really appreciate it.